# ubuntu VNC from my iphone Grey screen

Tags: vnc, tightvncserver

I am trying to VNC from my iphone to my ubuntu machine.

I have installed vncserver on my machine and I can go to my terminal and type vncserver and I get the log:

## Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Feb 25 2015 23:02:21

Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc

Sun Sep 23 23:35:10 2018
vncext:      VNC extension running!
vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5901
vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0

error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy

Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!

Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!

Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!

Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!

Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!

Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/, removing from list!

XKB extension not present on :1

Error:            XKB extension not present on :1

```
              Exiting
```

Starting session: /etc/X11/Xsession

Session terminated with return code 0.#

I can connect to the session If I use correct IP ADDRESS, but I only get a grey screen.

Here is my startup file

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop: 
unset SESSION_MANAGER
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
gnome-session –session=gnome-classic &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
```

I beleive the server is running in some limited capacity as I can connect to a grey screen (only if i use the correct IP) but i get disconnected if I  write

vncserver -kill :1

Ant help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a vnc server offered in the Ubuntu packages, like x11vnc or vnc4server.  Then when it is run, it will find the libraries and configuration files in their expected locations.

Comment: Thanks but I already have vnc4server and I think 11vnc also. I think there might be a problem with my path. you can see in my logs it tries                                "Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/" . any help is greatly appreciated